# comparing maps and setting the values of one map to anothe rmap

Tags: groovy

I have two maps as below(these are the logs of my output...sorry for the bad groovy)

```
map1 = [
  [ "name1":value1, "name2":value2,  "name3":value3  ],
  [ "name1":value1, "name2":value20, "name3":value30 ]
]

map2 = [
  [ "name1":value1, "name2":value4, "name3":value5, "name4":value6 ],
  [ "name1":value1, "name2":value7, "name3":value8, "name4":value9 ]
]
```

I need to set the values of name2 and name3 of map1 to name2 and name3 of map2 when "name1":value1 in both the maps

Required output:

```
map2 = [
  [ "name1":value1, "name2":value2,  "name3":value3,  "name4":value6 ],
  [ "name1":value1, "name2":value20, "name3":value30, "name4":value9 ]
]
```

I tried looping through both of them, but there is an overwrite(as it is a map) and the result is as below

> map2 = [
>         [ "name1":value1, "name2":value20, "name3":value30, "name4":value9 ],
>         [ "name1":value1, "name2":value20, "name3":value30, "name4":value9 ]
>       ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, they (map1 and map2) are lists and not maps.

Taking into consideration, the cardinality of both the lists are same, simplistically you can achieve the same by:

```
list2.eachWithIndex{item, i ->
   if(list2[i].name1 == list1[i].name1){
       list2[i].name2 = list1[i].name2
       list2[i].name3 = list1[i].name3
   }
}

assert list2 == [
  [ "name1":'value1', "name2":'value2',  "name3":'value3',  "name4":'value6' ],
  [ "name1":'value1', "name2":'value20', "name3":'value30', "name4":'value9' ]
]
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting null pointer exception at list2.eachWithIndex ? but the list is not null(is it compatible with Groovy 1.5.6 ?)

Comment: I have just used the same code and just replaced with my list names

Comment: It worked for the same example I have given above...but throwing null pointer exception to my code...hmmm need to check and get back

Comment: I figured out the data issue which was throwing the null pointer exception...Thanks